# How can I store a string of encrypted data in an xml element?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, encryption, xml-serialization

So I have EntityFramework solution.  i have customized the context to insert an audit trail, and it stores the trail in an xml field.  the context serializes an entity and that is what is stored.  I have certain fields that i am encrypting before they are written to the db.  I have a helper class that uses AESManaged to perform the encryption.  The values that wind up being stored contain ascii special characters, and this causes an exception during serialization.

my question is, how should i hande these encrypted fields so that they can be serialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).  Just don't store anyway to decrypt it.

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = ...;
var asBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
var asBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(asBase64);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "don't store anyway to decrypt it" ?  and where should i be using this piece of code?

Comment: nevermind.  i figured out where you intended that to go.  I used in my encryption helper.  the string return from the encrypt method is now created via the convert to base 64 method you provided. thank you.